# Closing down amazon EMR temporarily

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-emr

I wanted to know if I can temporarily close down my EMR ec2 instance to avoid extra charges. I waned to know if I can get a snapshot of my cluster and closing the ec2 instances temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot currently terminate/stop your master instance without losing everything on your cluster, including in HDFS, but one thing you might be able to do is shrink your core/task node instance groups when you don't need them. You must still keep at least one core instance (or more if you have a lot of data in HDFS that you want to keep), but you can resize your task instance groups down to zero if your cluster is not in use.

On the other hand, unless you really have anything on your cluster that you need to keep, you might just want to terminate your cluster when you no longer need it, then clone it to a new cluster when you require it again.

For instance, if you only ever store your output data in S3 or another service external to your EMR cluster, there is no reason you need to keep your EMR cluster running while idle and no reason to need to "snapshot" it because your cluster is essentially stateless.

If you do have any data/configuration stored on your cluster that you don't want to lose, you might want to consider moving it off the cluster so that you can shut down your cluster when not in use. (Of course, how you would do this depends upon what exactly we're talking about.)

Comment: Cloning is not the right way for this. One would like to start a cluster only when required and should be allowed to stop when cluster is not being used.